# overwrite the file saved with react native fetch blob

Tags: react-native

I want to overwrite(not append) the file content with react native fetch blob. I have a text file with text "hey this is nida", I want to replace this text with "Hii, my name is nida".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile` rather than `appendFile` method.

BTW, I'd recommend switch over to react-native-blob-util package as react-native-fetch-blob is not being maintained anymore.

Comment: first I create  a  text file with fs.writeFile with some text in it....now I want to overwrite it's content. Not sure how to do it

Comment: If you do fs.writeFile again, it should overwrite it. Is it not overwriting it?

Comment: yupp, It does...I thought it would give file exist error...but nothing like that. Thanks

Comment: Great. Good luck

Comment: I am not able to find the file on device created with react-native-blob-util. I have saved them inside downloads directory but they are not there...fs.isDir() shows directory exists

Comment: can you please share how did you save the file?

Comment: ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.mkdir(dirs).catch(e=>console.log('er:',e));...this should create a directory at let dirs = fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/NewChats'...  it creates(if i try to create again it shows already exist) but i's not visible inside downloads folder or  anywhere.